# How to show that $ \int_{X} g d\phi = \int_{X}gfd\mu$ for every measurable $ g$ on $X$ with range in $[0, \infty]$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose  $f : X \to[0, \infty]$ is measurable and $\phi(E) = \int_{E} f d\mu$  where $E \in \mathfrak{M}$

Then show that $\phi$  is  a measure  on $\mathfrak{M}$ and $ \int_{X} g d\phi = \int_{X}gfd\mu$ for every  measurable $ g$ on  $X$ with range in $[0, \infty]$

My attempt : Let $E_1, E_2,E_3 .....$ be disjoint member of $\mathfrak{M}$ whose union is $E $

now observe that $\chi_{E}f = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \chi_{E_j}f\tag1$

and that

$\phi(E)=\int_{X} \chi_{E} f d\mu\tag2$

$\phi(E_j)=\int_{X}\chi_{E_j}fd\mu \tag3$

from $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$  we have

$$\phi(E)= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \phi(E_j)$$

If $E= \emptyset$, then $\phi(\emptyset)= 0$ this show that $\phi$  is  a measure  on $\mathfrak{M}$ .

Remaining part im not able to prove.

**My doubt** :  How to  show  that $ \int_{X} g d\phi = \int_{X}gfd\mu$ for every  measurable $ g$ on  $X$ with range in $[0, \infty]$

Comment: Prove it for simple non-negative functions and then apply Monotone Convergence Theorem.